# Getting "IgniteCheckedException: Requested DataRegion is not configured" on startup

Tags: ignite

I am using Apache Ignite 2.7.5 for Net on Linux + Kubernetes.
I've defined a Data Region "rates" in a node which holds a couple of **local** caches. The node starts up successfully. However, all other nodes on the cluster fail with the following error:

```
IgniteCheckedException: Requested DataRegion is not configured: rates
```

But why? The data region is used only on a single node and the cache mode for all the caches on that node are set to CacheMode.Local. All other nodes do not use data storage at all.

Is it possible to address this issue without declaring the same data region on all other nodes in the cluster?

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

A data region has to be defined for every server node explicitly. There are two reasons why regions are not configured globally:

1. You’d like to have a subset of the nodes to store data that will belong to a region.
2. A region of the same name can be given different RAM volume on different server nodes. This way you control memory allocation granularly - per node.

Thus, for your case, just add “rates” region configuration to configurations of every server node.

Comment: Thank you for the response. But what if I don't need the data region "rates" on the other nodes? Why would I have to define it on every node? In my Ignite cluster only two nodes contain any data, the other nodes only host services.

Comment: Sounds like you’re looking for a way to exclude those service nodes from a list of those that will store actual data. Is this your case?

Comment: Well, I assumed that if I configure a cache be a local cache, it should be deployed only on that data node and the service nodes should not be involved at all? Isn't it working that way?

Comment: CacheConfiguration could also contain node filtering (as services do), you can target nodes where you'll have your cache deployed. Here's an example https://github.com/gridgain/gridgain-advanced-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/org/gridgain/examples/datagrid/nodesfilter/CacheNodeFilterExample.java.